# Combine git add, commit and push at once

Tags: git, github

```
git add .
git commit 'fix careless mistake, typo'
git push
```

I often do above 3 commands to push my code but it kinda tedious sometime to fix very minor issue. Can I run those 3 at once?

Comment: Please do not think this way. Do not only fix the typo, fix the commit that introduced the typo and push everything once everything is perfect. Especially learn about `git rebase -i`. Pushing every commit at once is a bad habit.

Answer (score 0):

A bad answer:

```
git add . && git commit -m 'fix careless mistake, typo'  && git push
```

Without the push:

```
git -am 'a message'
```

If you are using git in a shell that support alias like bash you can do:

```
alias autogit="function _autogit(){git add . && git commit -m $1 && git push};_autogit"
```

Anyway I think you should pull before pushing.

Comment: for this `git add . && git commit 'fix careless mistake, typo'  && git push
` why do u want to skip the `-m` ?

Comment: @EuniceC I don't want to skip the `-m`, I didn't add it after copy/pasting from the question.